# ms teams power automate HTTP POST sending "attachment id"

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

below is the scenario i am trying::

- a payload is sent to MS teams channel using webhook
- using the selected message in the channel, we trigger "power automate" flow
- this flow will perform HTTP Post on the selected message using REST API POST with selected message as body.
- we notice that the payload received in the target host is not expected as per what is selected message, for instance, payload contains like this that is received in target host:

> {"teamsFlowRunContext":{"MessagePayload":{"Id":"1633540811919","From":{"Application":{"DisplayName":"alerts-test-hk-webhook","Id":"gmbs42a62l"},"Conversation":null,"Device":null,"User":null},"Body":{"ContentType":"html","Content":"<attachment
> id="806b91eb802b49db9c13e8903de936f6">","PlainText":null},"Subject":"","LinkToMessage":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:5463456345346ghdh@thread.skype/1633540811919"},"Id":"f:4abaa1b5-eb58-b8c7-5190-db70a3b28143","ChannelData":{"EventType":null,"InvalidateInvokeCache":null,"Team":{"Id":"19:sdrg4wt45gsrth4y4her@thread.skype","AadGroupId":"b948e56e-4ea4-456f-bff4-16108061827f","Name":null},"Tenant":{"Id":"8bcff170-9979-491e-8683-d8ced0850bad"},"Channel":{"Id":"19:f1b77b6a406d4f8ebfc33faefea1cf1a@thread.skype","Name":null},"Notification":null,"OnBehalfOf":null},"From":{"Id":"29:1vERchnRGPZujmen29j4aZQzb2OFhXvipxhkjd3z7LyDleTr9PWVn-OBk1mxLcVl6ejhk9kvdw4L1Ph6FFoY5VA","Name":"testuser","Role":null,"AadObjectId":"cf1a646f-7a9b-4e33-830c-2bd0282a93fe","Properties":null},"Conversation":{"Id":"19:f1b77b6a406d4f8ebfc33faefea1cf1a@thread.skype;messageid=1633540811919","Name":"buildeng-alerts-test-hk","IsGroup":true},"Locale":"en-GB","CommandContext":"message","LocalTimezone":"India
> Standard Time"},"cardOutputs":{"choice":"Retry"}}}

However, without using webhook, i.e manually typed or copy/paste in MS teams channel, and using the manually typed information or copy/paste, using the selected message in channel, triggered power automate flow, the payload is being correctly sent (as expected) like below payload received in target host :

> {"entity":{"teamsFlowRunContext":{"MessagePayload":{"Id":"1633540339359","From":{"Application":null,"Conversation":null,"Device":null,"User":{"DisplayName":"testuser","Id":"cf1a646f-7a9b-4e33-830c-2bd0282a93fe"}},"Body":{"ContentType":"html","Content":"\n<div
> itemprop="copy-paste-block">\n\n<div style="font-size:12px">Build
> <a
> href="https://example.com/job/hk-test/job/hk-inifniteloop/47/console"
> rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank"
> title="https://example.com/job/hk-test/job/hk-inifniteloop/47/console">(47)
> of <a
> href="https://example.com/job/hk-test/job/hk-inifniteloop/47/"
> rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank"
> title="https://example.com//hk-test/job/hk-inifniteloop/47/">(hk-test/hk-inifniteloop/47)
> failed on <a href="https://example.com"
> rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank"
> title="https://example.com/">(example.com)\n\n","PlainText":"\n\n\nBuild
> (47) of (/hk-test/hk-inifniteloop/47) failed on
> (teams-buildeng)"},"Subject":"","LinkToMessage":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/19:89nsad08dnd98fmhb-9dfijb@thread.skype/1633540339359"},"Id":"f:b2ad833d-b218-a077-de38-c89ef8563ab6","ChannelData":{"EventType":null,"InvalidateInvokeCache":null,"Team":{"Id":"19:f5f62v456v54b@thread.skype","AadGroupId":"b948e56e-4ea4-456f-bff4-16108061827f","Name":null},"Tenant":{"Id":"8bcff170-9979-491e-8683-d8ced0850bad"},"Channel":{"Id":"19:f5v2356264@thread.skype","Name":null},"Notification":null,"OnBehalfOf":null},"From":{"Id":"29:f4vw6vb65r6-OBk1mxLcVl6ejhk9kvdw4L1Ph6FFoY5VA","Name":"testuser","Role":null,"AadObjectId":"cf1a646f-7a9b-4e33-830c-2bd0282a93fe","Properties":null},"Conversation":{"Id":"19:3425v2345bv45v45b@thread.skype;messageid=1633540339359","Name":"buildeng-alerts-test-hk","IsGroup":true},"Locale":"en-GB","CommandContext":"message","LocalTimezone":"India
> Standard Time"},"cardOutputs":{"choice":"Retry"}}}

Please advise what caused this "attachment id" behaviour as we are automating the flow from jenkins to ms teams to http post to target host.

Comment: Could you please share any reference docs or repro steps which you are following, so that we can try from our end.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft: here is the step to repro :  create webhook for a channel in teams -> using webhook, send payload to ms teams -> using power automate, create a flow to POST the same  payload using HTTP POST(REST API) to target host. Compare between payload (received at target host) using  webhook with  without webhook (i.e manually typed the information)

Comment: This seems to be ByDesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more visibility, Adding the answer from the comment section:

This seems to be by design: Payload received in the target host is not expected as per what is selected message.